# Error "Application is improperly formatted" when clicking on URL

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, manifest

While hitting my application URL in IE I am getting this error "**Cannot Continue. The Application is improperly formatted.contact the application vendor for assistance.**"

And the details:

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : `http://localhost:8080/cachetest`

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of `http://localhost:8080/cachetest`, resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception reading manifest from `http://localhost:8080/cachetest`,: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [11/11/2014 11:30:26 AM] : Activation of `http://localhost:8080/cachetest`, has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [11/11/2014 11:30:26 AM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Exception reading manifest from `http://localhost:8080/cachetest`: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Xml.XmlException
        - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
        - Source: System.Xml
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestValidatingReader.XmlFilteredReader.Read()
            at System.Xml.XmlCharCheckingReader.Read()
            at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.

******Note: I am getting this error only in IE not in chrome. It is working fine in chrome.**** 
I am using eclipse and websphere.
Can anyone please help me with this? why i am able to run in chrome not in IE?**

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/702225/ie-doesnt-work-with-localhost-port) around the update on the 27th. It looks like it might be an issue with the character set of your index.html page. The quote from that response to make it work was

```
I just wanted to document the results. The original response included Content-Type:
text/html;charset=utf-8 and based on the correct answer, it should be: Content-Type: 
text/html; charset=utf-8 with a space between the type and the charset.
```